# What is the title of that house teleported to another world where he has this cooking system for magic balls and his house is powered by magic

Tags: story-identification, anime, manga, isekai

The house has shield against others, only the owner can get in and out. His house is powered by magic and he makes magic balls by cooking on his magical 'thing' and those are said to be valuable.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Sci-Fi Stack exchange! Can you please add any other details? This question has very less details and it would help the people trying to answer your question.

Comment: You have an answer now. If it is correct (and you have no obligation to accept an incorrect answer although it's polite to explain why it doesn't match), you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is *Demonic Housekeeper* or *Tale of Otaku and Demons*. I'm not sure which is supposed to be the official title.

It starts with the main character waking up in his house after being transported to another world. He takes his scooter and explores a bit. After running away from someone who was attacking him, he finds out they cannot enter the area around his house. It continues for a few chapters with various people trying to get through the barrier around his house. He attacks back with various household items that have been enhanced with magic.

After a few more chapters, he is helping some people attack an evil rich person. A bunch of the people he is helping get injured, so he makes 'healing pills' in his rice cooker.